# Node JS Stream Only works on first iteration

Tags: node.js, parsing, filestream, node-modules

I have a simple node app that parses a csv file into a string.  In my server file, I call a module that runs makes a stream and pipes it into my parser.
The problem is that is code works perfectly the first time it is run, but fails after that.  I've gotten a "Write after End" error so I believe there is something wrong with the stream or parser variable not being reset properly after each use.  Thanks for any help!

```
const express    = require('express');
const app        = express();
const path       = require('path');
const port       = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const formidable = require('formidable');
const parser     = require('./csvparse.js');
const fs         = require('fs');



//send the index page on a get request
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Example app listening on port: ' + port));
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html")));

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  //upload the file from the html form
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req,function(err, fields, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //get the path to the uploaded file for the parser to use
    var filePath = files.spinFile.path;
    parser(filePath, function(data) {
        if (data == null) {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
        }   
            res.send("<code>" + data + "</code>");
    });
  });
});
```

The module export function looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(filePath, cb) {

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    stream.pipe(parser);
    //when the stream is done, songsLog is complete and ready to be returned
    stream.on('close', function() {
        cb(songsLog);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the contents of your module.exports in another function.

```
module.exports = function(filepath, cb) {
    function parse(filepath) {
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath)
        etc...
    }
    return {
        parse
    }
}
```

then from your route, call parser.parse('file.txt') and you should have a new read stream.